# What factors prevent offline browsing software from downloading a site?

Tags: download, stripping

Why is it not possible to download the pages on this site - http://www.judicialcollege.vic.edu.au/eManuals/VSM/index.htm#13888.htm - using offline browsing software? Not sure if the issue is programming-related but I have a feeling some programming factors are involved. Can someone shed a light on this?